# .net C# - Winform getting Deactivated after "Not responding" message on title bar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a *ClientForm* (opened from *MainWindow*)  which has a search button which on click takes around 12 seconds to process.
During search if user has clicked on that form multiple times "Not Responding" text get appears on its title bar which is ok, but after search completes *ClientForm* will lose focus or will get deactivate and *MainWindow* will get the focus - which is an **issue**.

Below is the code snippet.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // this is a wpf window
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cf= new ClientForm();
        cf.Show();
    }
}



 // This is a winform 
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        // Do some processing
        Thread.Sleep(12000);
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Is this a .net framework issue?

I am not using background thread for search or have not used ShowDialog to display form. Would like to know how else this can be fixed and why this issue is occurring.

Thanks!!!

Comment: 1. Don't block the UI Thread, use an async procedure (so your Form can also give some feedback, eventually) 2. call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`

Comment: Thanks for replying. But as said in the question I would like to understand more about this error.
I can not use ShowDialog or async due to project requirement/limitation.

Comment: `Form` is not a WPF class, but WinForms. Are you somehow mixing those frameworks?

Comment: There's no *error*. This is the standard behavior of Windows / Forms. If you block the UI Thread, making the Form / Window unresponsive beyond a specific tolerance time span, the System will give feedback to the User on its own. If your Form is unresponsive for a longer time, the System may also decide that it should be terminated. -- Since you use `Show()`, the User is free to click another Window / Form of your applcation, which is also unresponsive since you're blocking the UI Thread. When the sync procedure completes, if a Mouse in was sent to a Window / Form, the Focus is moved.

Comment: As @Clemens mentioned, why on earth do you have this kind of mixed setup of Windows and Forms? Is this some kind of an *experiment*? Do you have Forms that come from a Library of sort? Why cannot you use `ShowDialog()` or use asynchronous procedures? You do know that this is all kind of weird, right?

Answer (score 0):

Using background threads, my own example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                
            }
            }

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                label1.Text = "Runing...";
                // Start the asynchronous operation.
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            label1.Text = "Complete";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = false;
                label1.Text = "Cancel";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But as said in the question I would like to understand more about this error. I can not use background thread due to project requirement/limitation.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help but I have got the answer to this weird behavior in below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/preventing-hangs-in-windows-applications?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Window with "Not Responding" is not the actual window as actual one is set to hidden and thus deactivated. To resolve this, I have remove the GhostWindowFunctionality and now there is no loss of focus.
Only cons is user can not move, minimize, and close the unresponsive application but we have task manager to close/kill such app.

```
// This is a winform 
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void DisableProcessWindowsGhosting();    

    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisableProcessWindowsGhosting();   // This will disable it
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        // Do some processing
        Thread.Sleep(12000);
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. There are better ways to do this that you should learn to do.

Comment: I am aware of proper solution and have already suggested it in my ques. But I wanted to understand more about why it is occurring and how it can be fixed without background or modal dialog.

Comment: And I would have really appreciated if you would have read the ques properly and answered it accordingly. Sometime you have to apply quick workaround first and then implement proper solution.